# How to negate white-spaces when opening documents

Tags: c#

I've made a Program where people can store documents on a network drive.
To view or open the data I use a Data Grid, where people can double click on the data and it should open with the in windows chosen standard program. But it does't work. It works only when the documents are stored local on the machines and not on the network drive.

```
List<ZeichnungInDB> selectedItemsList = dataOutOfDb.SelectedItems.Cast<ZeichnungInDB>().ToList();
if(selectedItemsList.Count > 0)
{
    Process.Start(autovuePath[0], @"\\192.168.100.4\\DMS\\Daten\\" + selectedItemsList[0].Dateiname );
    //Process.Start(@"\\192.168.100.4\\DMS\\Daten\\" + selectedItemsList[0].Dateiname);
}
```

The program crashes when I try to open the documents with the standard program and when there are some white-spaces in the name. If I use AutoVue I can open the data without a white-space, but when there are any white-spaces it says that the data can't be found.

I've checked the user rules for the network drive and I haven't any that occurred this failure.

Has anyone a solution for my problem, or should i just go with the straightforward idea of don't accepting any white-spaces in the name and how can I solve the problem, that I can open the documents with the standard program for the different types?

Comment: I'm confused, why is Whitespace capitalized throughout the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking multiple things here so let's try to answer them one at a time.

> It works only when the documents are stored local on the machines and not on the network drive.

Have you tried to open a command line to outside of the application to see if you can open a file from the network this way? Make sure this works first before even reading further.
Open up the command prompt and do that now.

```
Process.Start(autovuePath[0], @"\\192.168.100.4\\DMS\\Daten\\" + selectedItemsList[0].Dateiname );
```

Also, I would change this to something else.

```
var directoryPath = @"\\192.168.100.4\DMS\Daten\"; // I removed the extra slashes. Might have been causing a problem.
var fileName = selectedItemsList[0].Dateiname;
var fullPath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);
Process.Start(autovuePath[0], fullPath);
```

Also, it's "view" not "vue" and there's no reason to capitalize "white space". :)